# Parallax div sections with a slant

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background, parallax

How would I go about create several homepage sections, all with parallax background images and a slanted edge?

This is the design I'm trying to create: http://prnt.sc/ea0avx

If it helps, I'm building within Wordpress using Avada theme as my base.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.viget.com/articles/angled-edges-with-css-masks-and-transforms

The Author details how to write css such that the sections have angled borders.

Comment: That should be accepted answer, there is such a great explaination in source. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just transform the angled divs and over lap them off the screen.

```html
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
    }

    .angle {
        margin: -75px;
        top: 350px;
        height: 400px;
        background: green;
       transform: rotate(-5deg);
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .revAngle {
        margin: -75px;
        width: 150%;
        height: 400px;
        background: green;
        transform: rotate(5deg);
        z-index: 5;
    }

    .strait {
        height: 500px;
        background: pink;
    }

</style>

<html>
<div class="strait"></div>
<div class="angle"></div>
<div class="strait"></div>
<div class="revAngle"></div>
<div class="strait"></div>
</html>
```

http://codepen.io/kevinlbatchelor/pen/ggJmYK

Comment: how would you do that with a picture background without getting a hole between two images?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a parallax background effect use something along these lines of code.

**Example:**

```
.parallaxdiv { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

    /* The Full height */
    height: 100%; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I am not exactly sure what you mean by a slanted edge , but you can try to use CSS clip-paths to achieve a slanted affect.

**An example:**

```
.img {
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
}
```

**Please vote up if it helps !**